# Query help to set a default value

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I'd need to set the `l.status` to `Unsubscribed` when there is a record that matches using the following query. Could anyone help me with that?

```
select 
l.SubscriberKey,
l.EmailAddress,
l.listid,
l.Status
from _ListSubscribers l
JOIN _Subscribers s on s.SubscriberKey = l.SubscriberKey
where s.Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND l.listid = listid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update System Data View data with a Query Activity.  It's a read-only view.  You'll have to export the results in a Data Extension to a file and import it into the List or Publication.  Steps in the Automation would be:

1. [**Query Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/) to select subscribers to update
2. Export the Data Extension to a file using a [**Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/) activity.
3. Import the file with an [**Import Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/)

Comment: Hey Adam, Do I need to use update only if I'm updating the status in 'all subscribers' or do I need to use 'add and update'. Does adding 'add and update' will cause any issue?